# .NET Selecting an item using sublist in a list

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq

This is my List

```
locList.Add(New Location() With {.ID = "001", .Name = "KTYM"})
' 2 products
prdList.Add(New Product() With {.ID = "001", .Locations = locList, .Name = "Boost"})
prdList.Add(New Product() With {.ID = "003", .Locations = locList, .Name = "Pears"})


locList = New List(Of Location)
prdList = New List(Of Product)
locList.Add(New Location() With {.ID = "002", .Name = "TVM"})
' 3 products
prdList.Add(New Product() With {.ID = "002", .Locations = locList, .Name = "Horlicks"})
prdList.Add(New Product() With {.ID = "003", .Locations = locList, .Name = "Pears"})
prdList.Add(New Product() With {.ID = "004", .Locations = locList, .Name = "Colgate"})


locList = New List(Of Location)
prdList = New List(Of Product)
locList.Add(New Location() With {.ID = "003", .Name = "KNR"})
' 4 prod
prdList.Add(New Product() With {.ID = "B05", .Locations = locList, .Name = "CloseUP"})
prdList.Add(New Product() With {.ID = "003", .Locations = locList, .Name = "Pears"})
prdList.Add(New Product() With {.ID = "016", .Locations = locList, .Name = "Maggi"})
prdList.Add(New Product() With {.ID = "A07", .Locations = locList, .Name = "Dairy Milk"})
```

Each product have a Location. I want to select all the products from the list for a given location. How can I achieve it ? I am using .net 3.5 for CE device. Thanks for your help.

EDIT

```
Dim prd = From p As Product In prdList _
                  From loc As Location In p.Locations _
                  Where loc.ID = "001" _
                  Select p
```

here  prd.Count it returns zero.

Comment: what effort have you made?

Comment: i tried lot of combinations using Linq but it throws null reference 
:(. Let me update

Comment: please show that code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C# would be `.Where( p => p.Locations.Any( loc => loc.ID == LocIdYouWant ) )`

I think this might be the equivalent VB.Net:

`.Where( Function(p) p.Locations.Any( Function( loc ) loc.ID = LocIdYouWant ) )`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.I tried `Any`. I think 3.5 CE doesn't support Any(). I got compile issues. Let me try once again.

Comment: MSDN says it is included in 3.5 compact... maybe my VB.Net wasn't correct (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972(v=vs.90).aspx)